# Play custom file format using NAudio

Tags: c#, audio, naudio

I just want to try playing different format of audio files. Is it possible to do that, or maybe using other codec?

Comment: what audio format in particular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NAudio can make use of any ACM codecs on your machine by using the `WaveFormatConversionStream`. You need to work out for yourself what `WaveFormat` structure the ACM is expecting, although NAudio does come with a few common WaveFormats provided for you such as Mu and A-law. Use the NAudioDemo app to examine what ACM codecs are on your system and what WaveFormats they suport.

You also mentioned ogg. Ogg is not supported out of the box, but Yuval Naveh has implemented Ogg support for NAudio as part of his [PracticeSharp](http://code.google.com/p/practicesharp/) application. See the code [here](http://code.google.com/p/practicesharp/source/browse/#svn/trunk/NAudioOggVorbis).